# Issue with running a compiled rebar3 erlang application with erl -pa

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, gen-server, cowboy, rebar3

An erlang OTP application (nerlnetApp) that depends on cowboy **compiled and run successfully** when executed using the command: rebar3 shell, from application directory.

However, erlang shell cannot run in CI environment and therefore we decide to run it using the following method:

```
erl -pa jsx/ebin ranch/ebin cowlib/ebin cowboy/ebin nerlnetApp/ebin -eval "nerlnetApp_app:start(a,b)."
```

This command generates the following error:

```
{"init terminating in do_boot",
{noproc,{gen_server,call,[ranch_sup,{start_child,{{ranch_listener_sup,nerlnetInitiator},
{ranch_listener_sup,start_link,[nerlnetInitiator,ranch_tcp,#{connection_type=>supervisor,socket_opts=>[{port,8484}]},cowboy_clear,#{connection_type=>supervisor,env=>#{dispatch=>[{'_',[],[{[<<"updateJsonPath">>],[],jsonHandler,[<0.9.0>]},{[<<"isNerlnetDevice">>],[],iotHandler,[<0.9.0>]}]}]}}]},permanent,infinity,supervisor,[ranch_listener_sup]}},infinity]}}}
```

Link to [nerlnetInitiator](https://github.com/leondavi/NErlNet/blob/913c407372a22d113f2d7b64e0b0bd548b882656/src_erl/NerlnetApp/src/nerlnetApp_app.erl#L113) where init_cowboy_start_clear fails.
Link to [application directory](https://github.com/leondavi/NErlNet/tree/FullFlowCI/src_erl/NerlnetApp) with rebar.config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `nerlnetApp_app:start/2` is the callback function for the `application` behaviour - it's not meant to be called directly. Try this instead:

```
-eval "application:ensure_all_started(nerlnetApp, permanent)."
```

That will start all dependencies, including `ranch`, before starting the application itself. That should avoid the `noproc` error, which suggests that there is no running process named `ranch_sup`.